# How can I use Jenkins to support S3 IAM roles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm very new to jenkins. I installed the [S3 plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/S3+Plugin). I wish to use AWS IAM S3 roles to make the plugin work.

However, I can't find any way to configure IAM roles within this plugin. I can see only setting up the access key and secret key.

Has anyone used IAM roles with this plugin?

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

IAM roles are assigned to EC2 instances at launch.  There's nothing else to configure, thus your S3 plugin should just automatically work.  This is dependent on the plugin supporting IAM roles, which it looks like it does according to your link. You will have to assign the correct bucket policy though using the instructions also found at the link.

Comment: I have followed the instruction and created the IAM roles and assigned  to the machine while it launches. But when I was about to configure the S3 bucket for my jenkins job, I couldn't find any profile on Jenkins Web UI that I created on the AWS console.